# Windows Live Messenger disconnects when accepting Remote Assistance request

Tags: windows-live-messenger, remote-assistance

When I accept a Remote Assistance request in Windows Live Messenger, I immediately get the following message:

> Reconnect to Messenger
>
> Your connection with Messenger has been lost.
>
> Reconnecting in 0:59 seconds.

The person requesting the assistance sees that I've accepted the request but they don't see any problem on their side.

However, if the other person emails me a Remote Assistance request file (Invitation.msrcIncident), I can connect to them with no problem. Because of this, it doesn't seem to me like it's a networking issue. It works with my Win7 firewall off or on, and I have TCP port 3389 forwarded from the router to my machine. But I get the same results whether the requesting side is inside my router or outside of it.

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate with the latest version of Windows Live Messenger (Version 2011 - Build 15.4.3555.308). The requesting side doesn't seem to matter, but I've tried it with XP and Windows 7.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what happens when you put your computer in the DMZ in your router... just as a test?  Also, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306298 That is an important read.  Windows Messenger RDP requests don't use 3389.  They use a dynamically assigned port greater than 1024.  Step 3 in that article.  I know... doesn't cover why Windows Live Messenger gets killed.

Comment: check your logs? `Users\<user_name>\Documents\Remote Assistance Logs`

Comment: @Bon: I tried making my PC be the DMZ server, but no change. Thanks for the link, but since both PCs are inside my router, I think all the ports should be wide open, shouldn't they?

Comment: Ports @ the router, yes.  But turning off the firewall on the machine that has the WLM disconnection issue should have opened up the ports on that machine.  It's almost like one or more ports that WLM are using are getting closed at the request.  Check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2027572 for all the ports that WLM 2010 uses.  And what about straight RDP?  And you shouldn't have to forward ports through the router, for machines on the local network.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thanks, yes I did actually. I saved a log from just before I clicked Accept to just after. I didn't get much from looking at it, but you're welcome to take a look: http://chocolatesoftware.com/misc/MsnMsgr.txt

Comment: @Bon: Yes, I've tried it with the firewall disabled on both machines, but no change. Remote Desktop works fine - I connected the same direction, from the requesting PC to the accepting PC. I agree, port forwarding shouldn't be necessary in this case since both are inside the router. Mystified. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the log file above, it seems like things start the disconnect process at time 10:23:36.24, when it calls CHotmailService::DisconnectAndCleanupInternal. Also, I'm not seeing any events at that time in any section of the Event Viewer.

Comment: I realize you are connecting with computers behind the same router but it is possible that the router is still filtering traffic in some way that impacts the WLM negotiation but not the RA negotiation. Try disabling SPI (stateful packet inspection) on your router, if available.

Comment: @Jeremy: tried disabling SPI but no luck. Thanks tho, I think you're on the right track. I'll see if I can get a different router, or bypass it completely and see if things are different.

Comment: Here's an update after several months. I bypassed the Netgear WNR3500L router (so the cable modem is connected directly via ethernet to my PC) and Remote Assistance finally works. As I mentioned before, configuring the router to disable SPI (Stateful Packet Inspection, also called NAT Filtering on the WAN Setup tab of my router) and setting my PC as the Default DMZ Server didn't help. I called Netgear but they had no other suggestions on things to reconfigure. May be time for a new router but not sure which one. Thanks for any other suggestions.